# Past Perfect vs Present Perfect

Tags: difference, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-constructions

everyone! I was reading a book and there was like "After we have done our home tasks we went to the cinema"
I wonder why it's present perfect , bit not past perfect ?
Thank you beforehand!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be based on an error.

Comment: What is the name of the "book"? Without a source, it's impossible to know whether this is a typo, a question in an exercise or a mistranscription of yours.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the sentence does not make sense. This is just a typo or a mistake.

You would indeed need to use either the past perfect or the simple past here:

> After we *had done* our home tasks, we went to the cinema.

Alternatively:

> After we *did* our home tasks, we went to the cinema.

Incidentally, "home tasks" sounds unidiomatic also; the correct phrase would depend on context, but "chores" might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase itself is not present perfect; it is in two different tenses: present perfect and past continuous.

The second part of the phrase needs to be in future continuous to make it congruent and more similar to conventional English.

The word "after" implies that there are events that should follow doing chores. Therefore it makes sense for the second part of the sentence to become FUTURE continuous. "We will go to the cinema."